# How to quickly delete a column from a table containing 600 million rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large table upon which I wish to run this query:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
DROP COLUMN Zipcode
```

`Zipcode` data type is `varchar`.

This approach is not suitable as it's taking a long time and increasing the log space, and it goes on for hours. Can anyone guide me a unique and more sophisticated approach which will not affect the performance of database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280957/sql-server-drop-column-from-vlt-very-large-table

Comment: yes i tested it on 60 million row table, and it was going on for large time around 6 to 7 hours so at the end i canceled the query as its not a better approach

Comment: @user3494425 did you run this exact query? Or did you do it through some tool like SSMS? This query *will* run instantly. Maybe the table was just locked? In that case you must fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth be told I don't think you have any choice: `ALTER TABLE` statements like dropping a column can take a very long time on very large tables so I think you'll have to identify a windows of opportunity when you can get some decent down-time and go for it then. You might consider changing your database log model from `FULL` to `SIMPLE` or `BULK LOGGED` for the duration to help reduce log writes and possibly some of the time taken, but that definitely requires a time when you're not worrying about live transactional traffic.

Answer (score 3):

Did you actually test this? Dropping a column is instant. You don't have a problem to solve.

---

Ok, so it looks like you have a blocking issue. You have not yet followed up on my comment regarding this. You should.

If there's a transaction running that is using the table you want to alter then the alter must wait. Find out who is blocking access to that table. Run `sp_who2` and look at the blocked-by column.

Comment: Yes i tested the same query and it kept on going for hours, so i am bit worried to test it on 600 million row table

Comment: @usr That's not actually true: `DROP COLUMN` acquires a shema modify lock and it is explicitly stated in the documentation that `ALTER TABLE` operations such as dropping columns on very large tables can take a long time to complete and generate lots of log records (see 'Locks and ALTER TABLE' [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

Comment: @StevePettifer the locking issue has nothing to do with the data size. It has to do with concurrent access. Dropping a column never causes lots of log records because the table data is not touched at all.

Comment: I did not say locking had anything to do with size, but it has to acquire one. A large table likely has significant amounts of transactional activity making it harder to acquire the lock needed to drop. And I refer you to the documentation I linked where it says, and I quote, " The **modifications made to the table are logged and fully recoverable. Changes that affect all the rows in very large tables, such as dropping a column** or, on some editions of SQL Server, adding a NOT NULL column with a default value, **can take a long time to complete and generate many log records**"

Comment: Ok, the meta-data changes are fully logged but they are tiny. The sentence about dropping a column is either a documentation bug or for an edition older then 2005.

Comment: No, thats for 2012. And the evidence backs it up. Feel free to challenge MS if you think they're wrong or it'll never get reviewed.