# Possibly stalling UPDATE x SET y = NULL statement

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

We've deprecated a feature and are in the process of purging some data.  Before completely removing a column, which would require too much immediate application development, we'd like to simply purge the data it contains (which the applications support).

However, a simple `UPDATE foo SET bar = NULL` seems abnormally expensive. In a test copy of the database, it ran for more than three hours before we canceled it.

We attempted the query again with a table lock and a `READ UNCOMMITTED` isolation level, to no avail (canceled after another three hours).

The table contains approximatively 112000 rows and the column for each row contains about 41400 bytes (so we're purging more than 4GiBs worth of data).  While it's quite a bit of data, it occurs to us that copying the remaining columns over to a new table, dropping the old one and renaming the new one would actually be faster already.  Note that we don't know how much it would take for the `UPDATE` to complete otherwise, we stopped at 3h, but it could be 5, 6, 12, a day.

The table incurs exactly zero concurrent access during these operations.

Would anyone have any recommendations with regard to our scenario?  Is the copy+drop+rename really the best way to go?  And if so, any special recommendations to make it as safe as possible?

A possibly naive assumption of ours is that the DBMS would be able to enact a copy/swap strategy behind the scenes of a normal `UPDATE` statement if given sufficiently lax hints.  Is it possible?

Comment: Looks like a typical case of logging the transaction being more expensive than you expected. Try using a loop to update a block, e.g. 1000, rows at a time.

Comment: @HABO Sounds right, thanks. Looking at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90a44905-f3e3-4f82-9c83-e875a1bf1cb1/this-would-be-a-great-addition-to-tsql) there doesn't seem to be a "good" way to go about it (i.e. one that wouldn't require one to scan the table for each batch). A scan with our predicate (`bar IS NOT NULL`) takes a lot of time (already 7min and counting, which adds up very fast depending on the amount of batches). My guess is because of the size of the column the data is not inline in the row. Do you know of an idiomatic way to split such transactions?

Comment: A common approach is something like `update ... where FooId in ( select top 1000 FooId from Foo where Bar is not NULL )` and looping until `@@RowCount` is zero. In your case it may make sense to gather the appropriate `FooId`s in a temporary table and work through that to avoid the rescan of `Foo`. Either delete or flag the temporary table rows as you process them. And there's no harm in trying different block sizes, e.g. 100 rows, until you find a (relative) sweet spot.

Comment: @HABO I was afraid you'd suggest a temp table ;). Seems a tad convoluted but it'd definitely work. I'll sleep on it and decide tomorrow whether we do that or copy/swap the table. If you care much for internet points, feel free to post an answer-- you've been very helpful, thanks again.

Comment: Try reading some answers from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280957/sql-server-drop-column-from-vlt-very-large-table

Comment: @Stephan I did, thanks a bunch. I liked the unioned view approach, and we definitely would've used it if we needed to keep the dataset online during the operation. Since we didn't however, we took a little shortcut and rebuilt the table in a more straightforward way (answer below).

Comment: Glad I could help and that you figured it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up copying and swapping the table.

The [question linked by Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9280957) in the comments contains some useful pointers as to how to keep the dataset online during the operation.  Especially see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9284710) by Mitch Schroeter which essentially sets up a view unioning the old and new tables while the transfer takes place.

Because we didn't need to keep the dataset online, this was overkill (especially considering the rest of the dataset is pretty small). Instead:

```
CREATE TABLE _foobar (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, foo INT, bar INT NULL);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT _foobar ON;
INSERT _foobar (id, foo, bar) SELECT id, foo, NULL FROM foobar;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT _foobar OFF;
DROP TABLE foobar;
EXECUTE sp_rename '_foobar', 'foobar';
```

The whole operation took 14 seconds, which seemed difficult to beat for our scenario.

Some tips/comments:

- Ensure the `CREATE TABLE` statement produces a schema that matches (e.g. using tools like VS or SSMS).
- Don't forget about `IDENTITY` columns. This means you need to write the column list explicitly for the `INSERT` statement, and of course set `IDENTITY_INSERT` for the table. See the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) for details.

Conclusions:

- It would seem that according to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/90a44905-f3e3-4f82-9c83-e875a1bf1cb1/this-would-be-a-great-addition-to-tsql) there is no easy way to split a normal `UPDATE` transaction in multiple transactions to manage consistency at a higher level. As suggested there and by HABO, all solutions seem to require either a scan for the predicate of the request on every batch or the use of a temporary table to store keys of rows matching the predicate in one go and use that for each batch (which should always be faster since the PK is always indexed).
- It would seem that there is no easy way to do a copy/swap while keeping operations online either. Again, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9284710) for an approach where you manually setup a unioned view.
- If the rest of your dataset is pretty small (fast to copy in its entirety) and you don't need to keep it online, you may use the more straightforward approach above.  Disclaimer: Check with your DBA if you have one, this may be dangerous if you're not 100% sure of what you're doing.